# Enumerator tag name can't be accessed by the class object?

Tags: c++, enums

```
//In Analyzer.h

class Analyzer
{
public :
    enum color{red, green ,blue};
Analyzer()
{
     cout<<"ctor";
}
    ~Analyzer();
};

//In main.cpp
#include"Analyzer.h"
int main()
{
    Analyzer *Ana = new Analyzer();
    Ana->color c ;//Error
    Analyzer::color c ;//Ok
    return 0
}
```

I am confused why color cant be accessed by class object where as  by using classname it can be accessed .

Comment: The enum is a type in the class, therefore `Analyzer::color`. If it were a static member, that syntax would work. It's debatable about letting that syntax work in that case, however. Other languages choose only to allow access to static members with the equivalent of `ClassName::member`, just as inner types work in C++.

Comment: @chris::since enum is not a static one so it can be accessible through object right?

Comment: @viku The problem is not it being static or not. The problem is that it's **not an object but a type.**

Comment: It's not the object that contains the type, it's the class. That's why it makes sense for the class to be used to access it. I was merely comparing it with static members, which are instanced on a classwide basis, which is why access via class name is sensible for those, but in C++, a static member can also be thought of as having a relation to the object. It's like the member is part of the object, it's just the same for each object. That's why access via the object is sensible for static members. The enum type has nothing to do with the actual object.

Comment: @chris Actually, the type is contained by the *namespace* that is created when declaring the class.

Comment: @H2CO3, I'm sure there's a good point behind that, but could you be more specific as to what *contained by the namespace* means? From what I see, it should be `NamespaceName::InnerType` if that's the case.

Comment: @chris There's no problem with the syntax! It's just a very slight conceptual detail I read somewhere that 1. types (structs, classes, enums, the integer primitives in `<cstdint>`, etc.), are contained within namespaces, **and** that a class declaration automatically creates a namespace that belongs to the class and is named the same as the class. Basically it's just hair splitting.

Comment: @H2CO3, Oh, that's an interesting detail. No wonder I wasn't catching on :p Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Member access operators `->`and `.` can only be used to access data members, enum members and member functions of the class. BTW, accessing static data members and functions with these operators is perfectly legal, even though the left-hand side is not required for such access (the left-hand side is evaluated is any case).

These operators cannot be used to access nested types of the class.

In your example `color` is a nested type, meaning that `Ana->color` is not a valid construct. Meanwhile, `Ada->red` is valid.

Answer (score 2):

You can only access data members and member functions of the class by the arrow operator. Enumeration is a nested type.

Comment: Thanks, removed the non-static.